# What is the 'dot space filename' command doing in bash?

Tags: bash, export

When using bash shell, I sometimes keep environment variables in a text file which I copy/paste the content of, eg exports.txt:

```
export FOO=bar
export FIZZ=buzz
```

Someone showed me instead of copy/paste, I could type in the terminal

```
. exports.txt
```

which would have the same effect as copy/paste.

What is the mechanism by which this 'dot space filename' command works? It's hard to think of search terms for it.

I want to understand what is happening and the more general details of what this one-liner is doing.

Comment: Run `help .`  This is so short the Stack Exchange engine thinks it's too short to be a comment.

Comment: I wonder why all these questions occur also in this site. They have been answered many times in [so], [ubuntu.se] and [unix.se].

Comment: To run dot-space, you'd need to type `'. '  args`, with single or double quotes.  Otherwise the unquoted space is eaten up by bash when it parses the line into tokens (see "word splitting" in the bash manual).

Comment: In bash, an alternate name for `.` is `source`, which literally means "source commands from this file," at least to me.

Comment: An even more common question on _Unix & Linux_ is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58514/ (and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43882/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312573/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308109/ and ...)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `.` ("dot") command is a synonym/shortcut for the shell's built-in `source` command.

It causes the named shell script to be read in and executed within the current shell context (rather than a subshell). This allows the sourced script to modify the environment of the calling shell, such as setting variables and defining shell functions and aliases.

Comment: Actually, `source` is a non-standard and non-portable synonym/shortcut for the [POSIX-defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html) "dot" (`.`) command, not the other way around.

Comment: bash provides a non-standard `source` and a non-standard `.` in non-POSIX mode, both of which search the current directory even if it isn't part of `$PATH`. In POSIX mode, it provides a standard `.` which doesn't search the current directory, and no `source`. In neither mode is `source` synonymous with POSIX's `.` command.

Answer (score 32):

While the two existing answers are already excellent, I feel the example where the effect is the most "noticeable" so to say, is missing.

Say I have a file `script.sh` with the following contents:

```
cd dir
```

If I would run this script normally (`sh script.sh`), I'd see this:

```
olle@OMK2-SERVER:~$ sh script.sh
olle@OMK2-SERVER:~$
```

But if I where to source the script (`. script.sh`), I'd end up with this:

```
olle@OMK2-SERVER:~$ . script.sh
olle@OMK2-SERVER:~/dir$
```

Notice how in the second case the working directory of our main shell has changed!

This is because (as pointed out in the other answers) the first example runs in its own subshell (the `sh` process we start with the `sh`-command, this could have been basically any shell, `bash`, `dash`, you name it), it changes directory there, does nothing and closes. While the second example runs in our main shell, and thus changes directory there!

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example.

Script file: mytest.sh

```
cat mytest.sh

#!/bin/bash

myvar=1
mystring="Hello World"
```

if you try to print any of the above variables you will get nothing

```
echo $myvar
```

but if you do

```
. mytest.sh
```

or

```
source mytest.sh
```

and then

```
echo $myvar
```

it will print 1

Just a visual answer of what Spiff wrote

Comment: So interpreting your example, using `export` is only if those variables are to be used in subshells. I could omit `export` in the file if the variables are only to be used in the current shell. Is that right?

Comment: Quite right and I could say yes. However the use of the export command is more useful or more understandable if you think about the shell environment variables. For example $HOME or $DISPLAY. Yes you could use the export command to export  a variable on your shell session or any subshells but it will gone as soon as you terminate that session.